# Pentaho Excel sheet reading error

Tags: pentaho

I am trying to access an Excel sheet and perform actions on it. When I am running it, I get the below error. It is not reading the input file.

```
2015/04/29 13:11:42 - INPUT.0 - Opening openFile #0 : /var/opt/UTM/V1.2/data/DAILY_inputs/working/Input_29-04-2015.xlsx
2015/04/29 13:11:42 - INPUT.0 - ERROR (version 3.1.0, build 826 from 2008/09/30 11:30:46) : Unexpected error :
2015/04/29 13:11:42 - INPUT.0 - ERROR (version 3.1.0, build 826 from 2008/09/30 11:30:46) : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jxl/WorkbookSettings
2015/04/29 13:11:42 - INPUT.0 - ERROR (version 3.1.0, build 826 from 2008/09/30 11:30:46) :   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelinput.ExcelInput.getRowFromWorkbooks(ExcelInput.java:501)
2015/04/29 13:11:42 - INPUT.0 - ERROR (version 3.1.0, build 826 from 2008/09/30 11:30:46) :   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelinput.ExcelInput.processRow(ExcelInput.java:405)
2015/04/29 13:11:42 - INPUT.0 - ERROR (version 3.1.0, build 826 from 2008/09/30 11:30:46) :   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.BaseStep.runStepThread(BaseStep.java:2664)
2015/04/29 13:11:42 - INPUT.0 - ERROR (version 3.1.0, build 826 from 2008/09/30 11:30:46) :   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.excelinput.ExcelInput.run(ExcelInput.java*
```

Comment: You may want to read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), since you are missing some important points: what are you exactly trying to do, what is your code, etc.

Comment: Thanks. I shall go through that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know from your errors, there is a jar(Java library) file missing.
Could you do a quick check in Pentaho folder and look for this file.

`.../data-integration/lib/jxl-2.6.12.jar`

If it's missing, you could try to download and put it into 'lib' folder.

Download from here:
http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven/net.sourceforge.jexcelapi/jars/jxl-2.6.jar

Then restart Pentaho and try again.